# Simple word counter program in python

Tags: python, text-files

I have tried to create a really simple program that counts the words that you have written. When I run my code, I do not get any errors, the problem is that it always says: "the numbers of words are 0" when it is clearly not 0. I have tried to add this and see if it actually reads anything from the file: `print(data)` . It doesn't print anything ): so there must be a problem with the read part.

```
print("copy ur text down below")
words = input("")
f = open("data.txt", "w+")
z = open("data.txt", "r+")

info = f.write(words)
data = z.read()
res = len(data.split())

print("the numbers of words are " + str(res))
f.close()
```

Thx in advance

Comment: Why are you writing `words` to a file & then immediately read them back, when you could just use `words` directly?

Comment: @ScottHunter sorry I missed that ! But the issue is then that f file and z file are opened at the same time. You should f.close() before openning the file again to read it.

Comment: omg I'm stupid lol thx tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is beacuse you haven't closed the file after writing to it. Use `f.close()` before using `z.read()`

#### Code:

```py
print("copy ur text down below")
words = input("")
f = open("data.txt", "w+")
z = open("data.txt", "r+")

info = f.write(words)
f.close() # closing the file here after writing
data = z.read()
res = len(data.split())

print("the numbers of words are " + str(res))
f.close()
```

#### Output:

```sh
copy ur text down below
hello world
the numbers of words are 2
```

Answer (score 1):

After writing to `f` with `f.write`, you should close `f` with `f.close` before calling `z.read`. [See here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).